# PHP вставка части изображения

Tags: php, изображения, gd, imagick

Есть шаблон в PNG 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Средствами PHP нужно:

а) Обрезать (изменить размер?) скриншот под размеры экрана шаблона (экран вырезан, он прозрачный).

б) Придать перспективу скриншоту.

в) Вставить скриншот на прозрачную область шаблона.

Что нужно использовать - GD, Imagick? И как вставлять скриншот - по координатам или по маске экрана шаблона?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, стоит использовать ImageMagick. Он умеет искажать в перспективе, [по четырём точкам](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective) – что вам и нужно. И вот [примеры искажений](http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/distortImage?imagePath=Lorikeet&distortion=6) на php – вам понадобится Bilinear:

```
//Example 5 - Bilinear

$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath($this->control->getImagePath()));
$points = array(
    0, 0, 25, 25, # top left
    176, 0, 126, 0, # top right
    0, 135, 0, 105, # bottom right
    176, 135, 176, 135 # bottum left
);
$imagick->setImageBackgroundColor("#fad888");
$imagick->setImageVirtualPixelMethod(\Imagick::VIRTUALPIXELMETHOD_BACKGROUND);
$imagick->distortImage(\Imagick::DISTORTION_BILINEAR, $points, true);
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
echo $imagick;
```

Понадобятся 4 точки из исходного изображения – просто углы скриншота, и 4 точки, в которые они должны после искажения попасть – границы области экрана в PNG.

Ваш скрин не совсем хорош пропорциями: он квадратный, а у экрана iPad mini экран 4:3 (1024:768). Если вписывать по ширине, снизу останется пустое место. Если по высоте, край пропадёт из виду. Просто вписать – растянется в высоту.